# skip and take parameters to retrieve items from flist with rest api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I need skip n item and take next n item.
Here is my rest api using to do this. I searched and added this parameters to request bu its not work. Response is;

```
GET https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test14jan/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('announcement2')/items?$select=Title,Id$skip=0&$top=10 400 (Bad Request)
```

here is my rest api;

```
private readItems(skip, take): void {

this.props.httpClient.get(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id$skip=${skip}&$top=${take}`, 
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: Response): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncement[] }> => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response: { value: IAnnouncement[] }): void => {
        this.setState({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${response.value.length} items`,
          items: response.value
        });
      }, (error: any): void => {
        this.setState({
          status: 'Loading all items failed with error: ' + error,
          items: []
        });
      });
  }
```

how can I fix it

Comment: $skip does not work in SharePoint 2013/ SharePoint line OData REST. Please refer this link. There is a workaround for this  --> http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126565/issue-with-skip-in-rest-api

Comment: this post not clear enough.. ok I got need to use __next instead skip but no clue how I can use it